JSON simple parse example, gives a Swift error
I'm trying to understand how to use JSON with Swift - starting with even the first example here:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37
I try:
import Foundation
// Example JSON with object root:
let data = "{\"someKey\": 42.0,\"anotherKey\": {\"someNestedKey\": true }}"
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

And even this simplified example gives an error I can't seem to resolve -
error: MyPlayground.playground:5:35: error: no exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                                  ^

Foundation.JSONSerialization:7:21: note: candidate expects value of type 'Data' for parameter #1 (got 'String')
    open class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
                    ^

Foundation.JSONSerialization:13:21: note: candidate expects value of type 'InputStream' for parameter #1 (got 'String')
    open class func jsonObject(with stream: InputStream, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
                    ^


See how rsc's answer does it. You did not convert the string to Data. There are many answers there using JSONDecoder, which I highly recommend using, instead of JSONSerialization.

Indeed JSONDecoder is the way to go if you have an object you want to create from this JSON. If you insist on keeping it in a Dictionary:
let data = "{\"someKey\": 42.0,\"anotherKey\": {\"someNestedKey\": true }}".data(using: .utf8)
That results in an optional dictionary (or array), so you'd need to validate if you really got an answer.

let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) -> let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(data.utf8), options: [])
